# openCv4Android probleme width Core impelmentation

Tags: android, opencv

I'm using opencv in android but when I try to show my inputFrame I have an image not properly oriented and when I try to fix this width :

```
    mat=inputFrame.rgba();
    core.rotate(mat,matRotate,Core.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);
    return matRotate;
```

I have this error :

> cv.core.Core.rotate_0(long, long, int) (tried
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Core_rotate_10 and
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Core_rotate_10__JJI) E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: Thread-2365 Process: app.cm.ma.objectdetection, PID: 22533
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void
>   org.opencv.core.Core.rotate_0(long, long, int) (tried
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Core_rotate_10 and
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Core_rotate_10__JJI)
>                         at org.opencv.core.Core.rotate_0(Native Method)